# How do I create the Super User Logo in text?

Tags: discussion, logo

The superuser logo has a square bracket and a curly bracket. is there a keyboard or ascii character for the "eye" dot?

Comment: It's no worse than the "How do I create ASCII smiles" thread!

Comment: @Wil Wellllll.... I guess so. Hmmmm. On second thought it might not be particularly meta-ish.

Comment: I have edited it to be more question-ish. I think this will be a good thread, who can create the logo closest to the real one!

Comment: Hmm, this won't qualify for migration anymore. Nice edit @Wil

Answer (score 13):

The horizontal spacing is off, and obviously the curly bracket doesn't have the vertical asymmetry of the real icon, but how about the following?

## [<sup>*•*</sup>}

Here's a smaller version, which has better horizontal spacing, assuming you can see it:
[<sup>*•*</sup>}

However, this is a *bit* of a cheat as I'm using a unicode dot ( • ) and then making it superscript *and* italic...

Comment: most excellent; the small form is quite close!

Answer (score 9):

The best I got is [·} which was done with the 'middle dot' (Alt+0183) I don't think the spacing will allow you to actually create the logo just the ASCII chars

Also, if you take a close look at the logo, the curly braket is different on top and bottom. There's a forehead and a chin

Answer (score 5):

You just need to find the right font ;)

[image: Homizio]

[Homizio by Álvaro Thomáz](http://www.dafont.com/homizio.font?text=%5B%B7%7D&psize=s)

Answer (score 4):

### [•} Super **user**

Ok - Kind of lame, I'll try to do better!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the spacing would work regardless, its not possible to get the eye dot inside of the bracket the way it is in the logo.

Answer (score 2):

> **[**'***}***

or

> *['}*

or

> ['}

is the best that I got.

Answer (score 1):

## [°}

It obviously depends on character sets and fonts. I'm sure there must be many Unicode characters that would serve that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

[}

(It's his day off, and he's lying in)

Answer (score 1):

In Microsoft Word, it's possible to get somewhat close ;)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[*˙*}

Closest I can get. [ + DOT ABOVE (U+02D9) (italic) + } Eye should probably be slightly lower and to the left, but whatever.