# What is the "dot" character on super user logo?

Tags: support, logo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How do I create the Super User Logo in text?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1635/how-do-i-create-the-super-user-logo-in-text)

I try to find it in this [post](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1635/how-do-i-create-the-super-user-logo-in-text) but I didn't find my answer there.

Is it the:

- `·` **GREEK ANO TELEIA** *Unicode Hex 0387*

  or the
- `•` **MIDDLE DOT** *Unicode Hex 00B7*

Comment: I think it's an eye.

Comment: @DanielBeck That's the question he linked to?

Comment: @slhck Yes. You'll note how *nobody manages to answer it 100%*, indicating that it's a dot moved around to the proper position in a graphics program. And in that case, what's the point of this question?

Comment: @DanielBeck Yeah, I absolutely know – then just answer it saying that :)

Comment: @slhck Tom already did.

Answer (score 7):

*It's just a filled circle, placed at the right spot such that it functions as an eye...*