# Super User logo meaning

Tags: discussion, logo

There is always a meaning to the logos of certain brands.

Does Super User have a meaning to its logo? [Take consideration of the look of it.](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1635/how-do-i-create-the-super-user-logo-in-text)

Answer (score 13):

#### Does Super User have a meaning on its logo?

It represents a (happy?) face, presumably that of the user.

There was a competition run in 2009 when the original trilogy (Stack Overflow, Server Fault and Super User) were created to design logos for the sites.

> The final winner we decided on was Mogeek, with entry #425 (a late entry!). What I liked about this logo is its simplicity, while simultaneously referencing both the classic Mac OS “face” icon, and old-school ASCII art. This entry was consistently cited by my designery pals (and even Joel himself) as one they liked.
>
> [image]

Source [Logo Contest Winner for superuser.com - Stack Overflow Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/02/logo-contest-winner-for-superusercom/)

I have to say I like this a lot more that the two runner ups (and it would have been a lot harder to create an icon from the logo):

> [image]

> [image]

Comment: That bottom logo reminds me _a lot_ of the avatar of some well known StackOverflow moderator...

Comment: @Ray That would be https://stackoverflow.com/users/366904/cody-gray

Comment: Yeap! You found / knew them :)